# Store in svelte - over Writing statements in svelte store.js - using onDestoy or resetting the Object?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I've been experimenting a little with svelte, and I was wondering if I need to use the `onDestroy()` function?

My Case Scenario:
I  have this stored in my store file:

```js
export const timeZoneSelect = writable({timeZone1:'' , timeZone2:'' ,timeDif: '' });
```

which represents a single usage of selecting a time zone, and every time the person starts a new 'comparison', this object gets set back to empty strings like this :

```js
timeZoneSelect.set({ timeZone1: '', timeZone2: '' });
```

So, My question entirely is : do I need to use onDestroy instead of my current method? and what are the differences between them?

Thank you! and your answer is appreciated!

What I tried at the moment:
I Reset the Object into empty values like this:

```js
timeZoneSelect.set({ timeZone1: '', timeZone2: '' });
```

and did my research here :
MDN => [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_stores#making_stores_reactive_with_the_reactive_store_syntax)

svelte docs example => [link](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/ondestroy)

Answer (score 0):

`onDestoy` runs when a component is unmounted (or manually destroyed), whether you need to do anything via that hook depends on the component and just in general what you want to happen.

Usually you only ever need it, if you have to run cleanup code that is not managed by Svelte. E.g. if you create a component via a separate non-Svelte library which requires something like a `destroy` call of its own.

The MDN example uses `onDestroy` because there was a manual store subscription via the `subscribe` function. If you do not have manual subscriptions and just use `$store` instead, all subscriptions are cleaned up automatically by Svelte.

---

Also, instead of having just one store and resetting it, why not just create a new one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer first of all, Can you elaborate more on 'How to create a new Store'? , I am basically creating a store each time I reset it, I haven't found a way to create a store without having to set it up in store file. 

Thanks!

Comment: You can create stores anywhere, including just in a component. By putting the store in a separate file and exporting it, you can only ever have one singleton instance. If you create the store in a component there is one store per component, though usually in components you do not even need stores because their state is reactive by default.

Comment: that's what I have right now, a general file that write the data into and I reset that same 'store value', Thank you Very much!

Comment: also I had an issue, that the values do not get 'cleaned up' , so i'll look into that.

Comment: I only explained how you are limiting yourself to one instance by putting exporting the store from a file, that was ***not*** a suggestion that one should do that. In general I would not recommend this.